# Python relative imports from parent directory

Tags: python, import

Here is the file structure I have :

```
app/
    main.py
    folder/
        a.py
        b.py
```

In the file `a.py` i have `import b`, and in `main.py`, i have `import folder.a`.

When I run `python3 a.py` from `folder/`, everything works fine. However when I run `python3 main.py` from `app/`, I get `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named b`, which is caused by the import in `a.py`

I have found a way to avoid this, which is to simply put `import folder.b` in `a.py`, but this is not very satisfying, as I can no longer lauch `a.py` from `folder/`.

What should i do for the import to work from both folder ? Please don't answer my question by saying i should modify my architecture, i've been looking for answers to this question on SO for 2 hours but i haven't found anything convincing.

Answer (score 0):

In a.py try:

```
from folder import b
```

or:

```
from folder.anotherfolder import b
```

or in main.py:

```
from folder import a, b
```

or:

```
from folder.anotherfolder import a, b
```